# Is there any solution that I can output 4k@60Hz and 3440*1440@60Hz with GTX 750Ti?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, displayport

I have a build of i7-4790 + GTX 750Ti computer, I have a PB287q monitor and plan to buy a 34 inches monitor with 3440 *1440 resolution. I don't want to up upgrade my Graphic cards due to its well-done job last year.

Is there any solution that I can output 3440 * 1440 @60Hz and 4K@60Hz at the same time with GTX 750Ti(2 HDMI + 1 DP).

Comment: The hardware you have simply is not powerful enough to do what you describe.  The max resolutions that the GTX 750 TI and the i7-4790 are documented.  If you want better resolution, you have to upgrade your hardware, this isn't something software can fix.

Comment: @Ramhound thanks for replying, I know it's not powerful, but there are some reasons, if I upgrade the graphic card, I have to upgrade the power supply which now is 385w, and I have to upgrade the mother board which means too many troubles for me. So I just want to buy a new 3440 * 1440 monitor and still use my old build.

Comment: You can use the monitor.  You just can't set it to those resolutions at those refresh speeds.  The GTX 750 TI will support 4k, I have doubts, it does it at 60 Hz though.

Comment: @Ramhound, it has one dp, this can support 4k@60hz at one monitor, I'm considering to make it support 2.

Comment: You can't "make it" support 2.  It has one port capability of the resolution you want.

Comment: You don't have to change the motherboard if you just want to replace the graphics card

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc, maybe I have to because if I upgrade a graphic card, I also need to upgrade my power supply which is now 385w.

Comment: The mainboard has no relation whatsoever with the power supply. Just upgrade the power and GPU. All modern power supplies are ATX and is compatible with all mainboards